# Jquery Show Hide multiple Class on Click

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make an interactive map to show locations of a range of services - each service has it's own icon and I have a legend (menu) that needs to show the service when a link is clicked and hide all the other services. All services must show on first page load (before clicking any of the links).

I have set up each service (icon) as a class and applied the relevant class to a div that has relative positioning to make the icon sit in the correct spot on the map - the div is also used for tooltip functionality so I cannot change the html structure - I need the show/hide to work on classes not divs (there are a lot of services).

I've almost got the show/hide working for the classes http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/363/ but it only seems to work AFTER you have clicked the link already once i.e. you need to click the link twice before it registers...

Here is the html

```
<div class="nav">
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="link1"><a href="#" data-page="page1">Topic One</a>

  </li>
  <li id="link2"><a href="#" data-page="page2">Topic Two</a>

  </li>
  <li id="link3"><a href="#" data-page="page3">Topic Three</a>

  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="page1">
     <h1>Show Page1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page2">
     <h1>Show Page2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page3">
     <h1>Show Page3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery:

```
$(function () {
  var curPage = "all";
  $("." + curPage).show();
  $("#menu a").click(function () {
    if (curPage.length) {
      $("." + curPage).hide("all");
    }
    curPage = $(this).data("page");
    $("." + curPage).show();
  });
});
```

Can anyone please help point me in the right direction to get it to work straight away? i.e. the page loads showing all classes then when a link is clicked first time it shows only the class relative to that link and hides all others.

I would really appreciate anyone's advice on how to achieve this - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/364/) is the fiddle what you want.

Just hide all elements and show that element only which is clicked.

```
$(function () {
    var curPage = "all";
            $("." + curPage).show();
    $("#menu a").click(function () {
        $("." + curPage).hide();
        if (curPage.length) {
            $("." + curPage).hide("all");
        }
        curPage = $(this).data("page");
        $("." + curPage).show();
    });
});

<div class="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="link1"><a href="#" data-page="page1">Topic One</a>

        </li>
        <li id="link2"><a href="#" data-page="page2">Topic Two</a>

        </li>
        <li id="link3"><a href="#" data-page="page3">Topic Three</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="page1 all">
         <h1>Show Page1</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="page2 all">
         <h1>Show Page2</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="page3 all">
         <h1>Show Page3</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your html as it is, just change the jQuery code to:

```
$(function(){

    $('#menu li').click(function(){
    var divClass = $(this).find('a').data('page');
    $('.main .'+divClass).toggle();

    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/365/

And if you want to show only one at a time, use this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.main > div').hide();
    $('#menu li').click(function(){    
    $('.main > div').hide();
    var divClass = $(this).find('a').data('page');
    $('.main .'+divClass).show();        
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/366/

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple with stack snippet attached:

```js
$(function () {
  var curPage = "all";
  $("#menu a").click(function () {            
    curPage = $(this).data("page");
    $("div[class='main'] div[class !='" + curPage +"']").hide(); // hide divs whose classes aren't curPage
    $("div[class='main'] div[class ='" + curPage +"']").show(); // show div whose class is curPage
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li id="link1"><a href="#" data-page="page1">Topic One</a></li>
    <li id="link2"><a href="#" data-page="page2">Topic Two</a></li>
    <li id="link3"><a href="#" data-page="page3">Topic Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="page1">
    <h1>Show Page1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page2">
    <h1>Show Page2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="page3">
    <h1>Show Page3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd make the mark up more meaningful/semantic. Give each of your sections an ID and link to there. That way on the rare occation that javascript is disabled your links still do someting.

```js
$(function () {

    $("#menu a").click(function () {
        $(".main>div").not($(this).attr("href")).hide(); //Hide All Other Div in main
        
        $($(this).attr("href")).show(); //Show the target div
        return false; // stop click default
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="link1"><a href="#page1">Topic One</a>

        </li>
        <li id="link2"><a href="#page2">Topic Two</a>

        </li>
        <li id="link3"><a href="#page3">Topic Three</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div id="page1">
         <h2>Show Page1</h2>

    </div>
    <div id="page2">
         <h2>Show Page2</h2>

    </div>
    <div id="page3">
         <h2>Show Page3</h2>

    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/M3ZhV/367/)

On a side note I've changed `h1` to `h2` as this is prefered from an SEO perspective.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer to my question - much appreciated. The fiddle wasn't the exact markup I was using for the interactive map - just a play to try and get the jquery to work. Thanks again for taking the time to make suggestions on this. :)